# Is it possible to use the same code in ImageButton and Button widgets in android?

Tags: android, xml, button, layout, imagebutton

I am developing an android application.

My requirement is to use same code run by two different control one is imageButton and second is Button.

For that i am using the method that is.

```
 public void onClick_Office_Mgmt(View v)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(Admin_Dashboard.this,Office_Mgmt.class);        
        i.putExtra("USERNAME", unm);        
        startActivity(i);   
    }
```

I use this method to Buttons OnClick event.

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_office_mgt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:onClick="onClick_Office_Mgmt"
            android:text="Office Mgt"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"/>
```

But when i try to call the same method in imageButtons OnClick event it causes an error.

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibtn_office_mgt"
            android:layout_width="108dp"
            android:layout_height="108dp"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:onClick="onClick_Office_Mgmt"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/office_icon" />
```

Can anyone tell why it occurs? and how to solve the problem?

My LogCat Error is:

```
02-12 05:27:24.134: E/ActivityThread(601): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d1edf0 that was originally bound here
02-12 05:27:24.134: E/ActivityThread(601): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d1edf0 that was originally bound here
02-12 05:27:24.134: E/ActivityThread(601):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-12 05:27:24.134: E/ActivityThread(601):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-12 05:27:24.134: E/ActivityThread(601):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-12 05:27:24.134: E/ActivityThread(601):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-12 05:27:24.134: E/ActivityThread(601):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-12 05:27:24.134: E/ActivityThread(601):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-12 05:27:24.134: E/ActivityThread(601):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-12 05:27:24.134: E/ActivityThread(601):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
02-12 05:27:24.134: E/ActivityThread(601):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
02-12 05:27:24.134: E/ActivityThread(601):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-12 05:27:24.134: E/ActivityThread(601):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-12 05:27:24.134: E/ActivityThread(601):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-12 05:27:24.134: E/ActivityThread(601):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-12 05:27:24.134: E/ActivityThread(601):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-12 05:27:24.134: E/ActivityThread(601):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-12 05:27:24.134: E/ActivityThread(601):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-12 05:27:24.153: E/StrictMode(601): null
02-12 05:27:24.153: E/StrictMode(601): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d1edf0 that was originally bound here
02-12 05:27:24.153: E/StrictMode(601):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-12 05:27:24.153: E/StrictMode(601):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-12 05:27:24.153: E/StrictMode(601):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-12 05:27:24.153: E/StrictMode(601):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-12 05:27:24.153: E/StrictMode(601):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-12 05:27:24.153: E/StrictMode(601):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-12 05:27:24.153: E/StrictMode(601):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-12 05:27:24.153: E/StrictMode(601):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
02-12 05:27:24.153: E/StrictMode(601):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
02-12 05:27:24.153: E/StrictMode(601):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-12 05:27:24.153: E/StrictMode(601):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-12 05:27:24.153: E/StrictMode(601):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-12 05:27:24.153: E/StrictMode(601):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-12 05:27:24.153: E/StrictMode(601):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-12 05:27:24.153: E/StrictMode(601):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-12 05:27:24.153: E/StrictMode(601):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-12 05:27:24.183: W/ActivityManager(285): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@4144d778
02-12 05:27:24.204: E/ActivityThread(601): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d1f2b8 that was originally bound here
02-12 05:27:24.204: E/ActivityThread(601): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d1f2b8 that was originally bound here
02-12 05:27:24.204: E/ActivityThread(601):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-12 05:27:24.204: E/ActivityThread(601):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-12 05:27:24.204: E/ActivityThread(601):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-12 05:27:24.204: E/ActivityThread(601):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-12 05:27:24.204: E/ActivityThread(601):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-12 05:27:24.204: E/ActivityThread(601):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-12 05:27:24.204: E/ActivityThread(601):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-12 05:27:24.204: E/ActivityThread(601):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
02-12 05:27:24.204: E/ActivityThread(601):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
02-12 05:27:24.204: E/ActivityThread(601):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
02-12 05:27:24.204: E/ActivityThread(601):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-12 05:27:24.204: E/ActivityThread(601):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-12 05:27:24.204: E/ActivityThread(601):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-12 05:27:24.204: E/ActivityThread(601):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-12 05:27:24.204: E/ActivityThread(601):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-12 05:27:24.204: E/ActivityThread(601):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-12 05:27:24.204: E/ActivityThread(601):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: which error you are getting?

Comment: I got runtime error. My application calls webservice but when I change Imagebutton into button its not working

Comment: post the logcat error stack trace...

Comment: Sure. Now check the log in the question please.

Comment: Still facing problem or problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcorse it is possible.

I think you have an error because of declaration of widgets.

You can use it via method.

Just the thing is you must remove declaration of buttons and imagebutton.

Like

button1=(button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);

Comment: I had removed the declaration and it worked. Thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is coming when you are using emulator to do testing. A simpler fix is to disable **"Exchange Services"** in the emulated device under

> Settings -> Apps -> All

Second solution is, you can remove your current emulator and create the same one. Sometimes this solves it.

**Edit**

If Host GPU in emulator is enabled, just disable it and try again.

What you are getting problem is related with emulator. If you have a device, try to check it there once. This will save your time.

Comment: Ofcorse i had initialized it before through another intent.

Comment: can you please add logs to more identify the problem

Comment: Sure. Now check the log in the question please.

Comment: Still the problem remails sir.

Comment: Try to check once in original device then.